# how set images on buttons of navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I need to put images on add,cancel and back buttons of navigation bar. I have done with add button but not getting for back button.

even with this add button image it shows back blue color custom button.how to set for this?

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_add_button.png"] 
    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self               
    action:@selector(addNote)];
```

Comment: You are showing us the `addButton` code.

Comment: this is how i have put image on add button.and trying for back button and cancel button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Initialize the UIButton
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

// Initialize the UIBarButtonItem
UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

// Set the Target and Action for aButton
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Then you can add the aBarButtonItem to the UINavigationBar
...
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;

// Release buttonImage
[buttonImage release];
```

Comment: it gives error while initializing the UIBarButtonItem that interface type cannot be statically allocated

Comment: the * was remaining at beginning of bBarButtonItem

Comment: @Heena Dave my mistake see updated code. UIBarButtonItem is an object and i forget to put a *.

Comment: @Heena Dave. Are you new to iPhone development?

Comment: yes i m completely new to iphone development.that is why my questions are too core.!!