# set size of an image programatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

is there any way I can set the size of an image in my NavigationBar programatically instead of changing in manually?

Here is the code which creates the button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *Share = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_share.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Share:)];
```

My images size is 256*256 so it simply show up in this resolution and whole screen is messed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to change the size of your image? If so, something like this should work:

```
// Given a UIImage image and a CGSize newSize:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then use `newImage` for the image of the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: You have to first declare your UIImage obviously, and also set a CGSize newsize. But that should work if I'm not mistaken. Also, this might help if you still have trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435118/how-set-images-on-buttons-of-navigation-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Normaly you should use `contentMode` (in this case `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`) every UIView subclass have this property usually you might use it to `UIImageView`. But i'm almost sure that does not work with `UIBarButtonItem`. Try, but you might hit a wall.

If my prediction was true you have to resize image programatically:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_share"];
float maximumHeight = 44;
float ratio = maximumHeight/ myImage.size.height;
CGSize imageNewSize = CGSizeMake(myImage.size.width*ratio, maximumHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageNewSize, NO, 0.0);
[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageNewSize.width, imageNewSize.height)];
UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIBarButtonItem *Share = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:resizedImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Share:)];
```

Comment: yes but this has just adjusted the height of image. Once I try to adjust maximumWidth the error pops up: redefinition of ratio.

Comment: Ooo i made a mistake. Change third line from `float ratio = myImage.size.height/maximumHeight;` to `float ratio = maximumHeight/ myImage.size.height;`

Comment: If you have redefinition error you should look for this redefinition (you declare the same variable name twice).

Comment: But there already is `float ratio = maximumHeight/ myImage.size.height;`

Comment: Yes, now i edit my answer. change it, not add it. If you have redefinition error, like i said you have variable ratio declared twice. Change name or remove redefinition.

Comment: Ok I've solved it with Marcel Puyat's solution already! Thank you